# JSON attributes into loop

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have converted some XML into JSON output.
Now when I want to loop the values and want to echo. I am confused and not able to get it worked. I just need if anyone can give me the idea or point me where I am wrong.

Here is my actual JSON output. I have formatted this output in notepad

```
{
   "@attributes":{
      "NMchs":"10"
   },
   "links":{
      "@attributes":{
         "fUrlBase":"http:\/\/synd.cricbuzz.com\/j2me\/1.0\/flags\/team_"
      }
   },
   "match":[
      {
         "@attributes":{
            "id":"3",
            "type":"T20",
            "srs":"Indian Premier League 2013",
            "mchDesc":"KOL vs CHN",
            "mnum":"26th Match",
            "vcity":"Kolkata",
            "vcountry":"India",
            "grnd":"Eden Gardens",
            "inngCnt":"1",
            "datapath":"http:\/\/synd.cricbuzz.com\/j2me\/1.0\/match\/2013\/2013_T20_LEAGUE\/KOL_CHN_APR20\/"
         },
         "state":{
            "@attributes":{
               "mchState":"inprogress",
               "status":"KOL elect to bat",
               "TW":"Kolkata",
               "decisn":"Batting",
               "addnStatus":"",
               "splStatus":""
            }
         },
         "Tm":[
            {
               "@attributes":{
                  "id":"63",
                  "Name":"Kolkata",
                  "sName":"KOL",
                  "flag":"0"
               }
            },
            {
               "@attributes":{
                  "id":"58",
                  "Name":"Chennai",
                  "sName":"CHN",
                  "flag":"0"
               }
            }
         ],
         "Tme":{
            "@attributes":{
               "Dt":"Apr 20 2013",
               "stTme":"10:30",
               "enddt":"Apr 20 2013"
            }
         },
         "mscr":{
            "inngsdetail":{
               "@attributes":{
                  "noofovers":"50",
                  "rrr":"0",
                  "crr":"6.49",
                  "cprtshp":"11(13)"
               }
            },
            "btTm":{
               "@attributes":{
                  "id":"63",
                  "sName":"KOL"
               },
               "Inngs":{
                  "@attributes":{
                     "desc":"Inns",
                     "r":"66",
                     "Decl":"0",
                     "FollowOn":"0",
                     "ovrs":"10.1",
                     "wkts":"4"
                  }
               }
            },
            "blgTm":{
               "@attributes":{
                  "id":"58",
                  "sName":"CHN"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

There is 4-5 similar data in the output. Below is the file in which I am trying to loop the fields to echo with variable.

```
<?php
require_once("xml2json.php");

$testXmlFile = 'test.xml';

$xmlStringContents = file_get_contents($testXmlFile); 
$jsonContents = "";

$jsonContents = xml2json::transformXmlStringToJson($xmlStringContents);
echo($jsonContents);

$obj = json_decode($jsonContents);

foreach ($obj->match as $match) {
    echo $match ->id,"<br>";
    echo $match ->attributes->type,"<br>";
    echo $match ->attributes->srs,"<br>";
    echo $match ->attributes->mchDesc,"<br>";
    echo $match ->attributes->mnum,"<br>";
    echo $match ->attributes->vcity,"<br>";
    echo $match ->attributes->vcountry,"<br>";
    echo $match ->attributes->grnd,"<br>";
    echo $match ->attributes->inngCnt,"<br>";
    echo $match ->attributes->state->attributes->mchState,"<br>";
    echo $match ->attributes->state->attributes->status,"<br>";
    echo $match ->attributes->state->attributes->TW,"<br>";
    echo $match ->attributes->state->attributes->decisn,"<br>";
    echo $match ->attributes->state->attributes->addnStatus,"<br>";
    echo $match ->attributes->state->attributes->splStatus,"<br>";
    echo $match ->attributes->Tm->attributes->id,"<br>";
    echo $match ->attributes->Tm->attributes->Name,"<br>";
    echo $match ->attributes->Tm->attributes->sName,"<br>";
    echo $match ->attributes->Tm->attributes->flag,"<br>";
    echo $match ->attributes->Tm->attributes->attributes->id,"<br>";
    echo $match ->attributes->Tm->attributes->attributes->Name,"<br>";
    echo $match ->attributes->Tm->attributes->attributes->sName,"<br>";
}
?>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @soyuka I didnt get .. Please elaborate ..

Comment: I think he means use print_r to analyze $match, so that you can see how you should echo out the properties.

Comment: I've elaborate on my _answer_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

decode of your json is below attention to structure

```
 stdClass Object
(
   [@attributes] => stdClass Object
    (
        [NMchs] => 10
    )

   [links] => stdClass Object
    (
        [@attributes] => stdClass Object
            (
                [fUrlBase] => http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/flags/team_
            )

    )

    [match] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [@attributes] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [type] => T20
                        [srs] => Indian Premier League 2013
                        [mchDesc] => KOL vs CHN
                        [mnum] => 26th Match
                        [vcity] => Kolkata
                        [vcountry] => India
                        [grnd] => Eden Gardens
                        [inngCnt] => 1
                        [datapath] => http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/match/2013/2013_T20_LEAGUE/KOL_CHN_APR20/
                    )

                [state] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [mchState] => inprogress
                                [status] => KOL elect to bat
                                [TW] => Kolkata
                                [decisn] => Batting
                                [addnStatus] => 
                                [splStatus] => 
                            )

                    )

                [Tm] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [@attributes] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [id] => 63
                                        [Name] => Kolkata
                                        [sName] => KOL
                                        [flag] => 0
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [@attributes] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [id] => 58
                                        [Name] => Chennai
                                        [sName] => CHN
                                        [flag] => 0
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [Tme] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [Dt] => Apr 20 2013
                                [stTme] => 10:30
                                [enddt] => Apr 20 2013
                            )

                    )

                [mscr] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [inngsdetail] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [@attributes] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [noofovers] => 50
                                        [rrr] => 0
                                        [crr] => 6.49
                                        [cprtshp] => 11(13)
                                    )

                            )

                        [btTm] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [@attributes] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [id] => 63
                                        [sName] => KOL
                                    )

                                [Inngs] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [desc] => Inns
                                                [r] => 66
                                                [Decl] => 0
                                                [FollowOn] => 0
                                                [ovrs] => 10.1
                                                [wkts] => 4
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [blgTm] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [@attributes] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [id] => 58
                                        [sName] => CHN
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

 )
```

you should change foreach code

```
  foreach ($obj->match as $match) {
    echo $match ->{'@attributes'}->type,"<br>";
    echo $match ->{'@attributes'}->srs,"<br>";
    echo $match ->{'@attributes'}->mchDesc,"<br>";
    echo $match ->{'@attributes'}->mnum,"<br>";
    echo $match ->{'@attributes'}->vcity,"<br>";
    echo $match ->{'@attributes'}->vcountry,"<br>";
    echo $match ->{'@attributes'}->grnd,"<br>";
    echo $match ->{'@attributes'}->inngCnt,"<br>";
    echo $match ->state->{'@attributes'}->mchState,"<br>";
    echo $match ->state->{'@attributes'}->status,"<br>";
    echo $match ->state->{'@attributes'}->TW,"<br>";
    echo $match ->state->{'@attributes'}->decisn,"<br>";
    echo $match ->state->{'@attributes'}->addnStatus,"<br>";
    echo $match ->state->{'@attributes'}->splStatus,"<br>";
    foreach($match ->Tm as $Tm){
       echo $Tm->{'@attributes'}->id,"<br>";
       echo $Tm->{'@attributes'}->Name,"<br>";
       echo $Tm->{'@attributes'}->sName,"<br>";
       echo $Tm->{'@attributes'}->flag,"<br>";
   }
}
```

**output as html**

```
 T20<br>Indian Premier League 2013<br>KOL vs CHN<br>26th Match<br>Kolkata<br>India<br>Eden Gardens<br>1<br>inprogress<br>KOL elect to bat<br>Kolkata<br>Batting<br><br><br>63<br>Kolkata<br>KOL<br>0<br>58<br>Chennai<br>CHN<br>0<br>
```

edit:

see json decode of https://cdn.anonfiles.com/1366532327809.txt it show you need put `$obj->mchdata->match` instead of `$obj->match` for this code change to:

```
 foreach ($obj->mchdata->match as $match) {
    echo @$match ->{'@attributes'}->type,"<br>";
    echo @$match ->{'@attributes'}->srs,"<br>";
    echo @$match ->{'@attributes'}->mchDesc,"<br>";
    echo @$match ->{'@attributes'}->mnum,"<br>";
    echo @$match ->{'@attributes'}->vcity,"<br>";
    echo @$match ->{'@attributes'}->vcountry,"<br>";
    echo @$match ->{'@attributes'}->grnd,"<br>";
    echo $match ->{'@attributes'}->inngCnt,"<br>";
    echo @$match ->state->{'@attributes'}->mchState,"<br>";
    echo @$match ->state->{'@attributes'}->status,"<br>";
    echo @$match ->state->{'@attributes'}->TW,"<br>";
    echo @$match ->state->{'@attributes'}->decisn,"<br>";
    echo @$match ->state->{'@attributes'}->addnStatus,"<br>";
    echo @$match ->state->{'@attributes'}->splStatus,"<br>";
    foreach($match ->Tm as $Tm){
       echo @$Tm->{'@attributes'}->id,"<br>";
       echo @$Tm->{'@attributes'}->Name,"<br>";
       echo @$Tm->{'@attributes'}->sName,"<br>";
       echo @$Tm->{'@attributes'}->flag,"<br>";
   }
}
```

**output as html**

```
T20<br>Indian Premier League 2013<br>DEL vs MUM<br>28th Match<br>Delhi<br>India<br>Feroz Shah Kotla<br>0<br>preview<br>Starts on Apr 21 at 10:30 GMT<br><br><br><br><br>61<br>Delhi<br>DEL<br>0<br>62<br>Mumbai<br>MUM<br>0<br>T20<br>Indian Premier League 2013<br>MOH vs PUNE<br>29th Match<br>Mohali<br>India<br>Punjab Cricket Association Stadium<br>0<br>preview<br>Starts on Apr 21 at 14:30 GMT<br><br><br><br><br>65<br>Punjab<br>MOH<br>0<br>183<br>Pune<br>PUNE<br>0<br>T20<br>Indian Premier League 2013<br>BLR vs JAI<br>27th Match<br>Bengaluru<br>India<br>M.Chinnaswamy Stadium<br>2<br>complete<br>Royal Challengers Bangalore won by 7 wkts<br>Bangalore<br>Fielding<br><br><br>59<br>Bangalore<br>BLR<br>0<br>64<br>Rajasthan<br>JAI<br>0<br>T20<br>Indian Premier League 2013<br>KOL vs CHN<br>26th Match<br>Kolkata<br>India<br>Eden Gardens<br>2<br>complete<br>Chennai won by 4 wkts<br>Kolkata<br>Batting<br><br><br>63<br>Kolkata<br>KOL<br>0<br>58<br>Chennai<br>CHN<br>0<br>T20<br>Indian Premier League 2013<br>BLR vs JAI<br>27th Match<br><br><br><br>2<br>Result<br>Royal Challengers Bangalore won by 7 wkts<br><br><br><br><br>59<br>Bangalore<br>BLR<br>0<br>64<br>Rajasthan<br>JAI<br>0<br>T20<br>Kenya tour of Namibia 2013<br>KEN vs NED<br>Only T20I<br><br><br><br>2<br>Result<br>Kenya won by 5 wkts<br><br><br><br><br>14<br>Ken<br>KEN<br>1<br>24<br>NED<br>NED<br>1<br>
```

Comment: Thanks for your expert answer . When I added your for each loop I got an error saying 

"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/####/public_html/cric/cric.php on line 12"

Please tell me how can I get that Json decode like you suggested above.

Comment: Thanks for beautiful piece of code and advice. But how will I decode the json as mentioned above by you ? Please guide me

Comment: this is a `json_decode()` output you put `echo($jsonContents);` before  `json_decode()` that show you json if you put `print_r($obj);` after  `json_decode()`  that show you this

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad mohesenipur. But still its giving me the warning 
""Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/####/public_html/cric/cric.php on line 12" and nothing is displayed. The line 12 is for each loop/.

Comment: Can you please check if the above code works for this https://cdn.anonfiles.com/1366532327809.txt This is the full JSON response I am passing and getting the error

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your XML converts to proper JSON, and json_decode returns something other than NULL. You could use this. Also, since you left the '@' character in your JSON, you will have to use PHP special syntax to retrieve that property, since the @ symbol is not valid for PHP variables. If you remove the '@' from attributes, then you will be able to use $match->attributes.

```
<?php
    $obj = json_decode( $jsonContents );

    foreach ( $obj->match as $match )
    {
        echo $match->{'@attributes'}->id . '<br>';
        echo $match->{'@attributes'}->type . "<br>";
        echo $match->{'@attributes'}->srs . "<br>";
        echo $match->{'@attributes'}->mchDesc . "<br>";
        echo $match->{'@attributes'}->mnum . "<br>";
        echo $match->{'@attributes'}->vcity . "<br>";
        echo $match->{'@attributes'}->vcountry . "<br>";
        echo $match->{'@attributes'}->grnd . "<br>";
        echo $match->{'@attributes'}->inngCnt . "<br>";
        echo $match->state->{'@attributes'}->mchState . "<br>";
        echo $match->state->{'@attributes'}->status . "<br>";
        echo $match->state->{'@attributes'}->TW . "<br>";
        echo $match->state->{'@attributes'}->decisn . "<br>";
        echo $match->state->{'@attributes'}->addnStatus . "<br>";
        echo $match->state->{'@attributes'}->splStatus . "<br>";
        foreach ( $match->Tm as $Tm )
        {
            echo $Tm->{'@attributes'}->id . "<br>";
            echo $Tm->{'@attributes'}->Name . "<br>";
            echo $Tm->{'@attributes'}->sName . "<br>";
            echo $Tm->{'@attributes'}->flag . "<br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Here's some sample JSON I used to test (taken from above and fixed).

```
<?php
$jsonContents = <<<EOT
{
   "@attributes":{
      "NMchs":"10"
   },
   "links":{
      "@attributes":{
         "fUrlBase":"http:\/\/synd.cricbuzz.com\/j2me\/1.0\/flags\/team_"
      }
   },
   "match":[
      {
         "@attributes":{
            "id":"3",
            "type":"T20",
            "srs":"Indian Premier League 2013",
            "mchDesc":"KOL vs CHN",
            "mnum":"26th Match",
            "vcity":"Kolkata",
            "vcountry":"India",
            "grnd":"Eden Gardens",
            "inngCnt":"1",
            "datapath":"http:\/\/synd.cricbuzz.com\/j2me\/1.0\/match\/2013\/2013_T20_LEAGUE\/KOL_CHN_APR20\/"
         },
         "state":{
            "@attributes":{
               "mchState":"inprogress",
               "status":"KOL elect to bat",
               "TW":"Kolkata",
               "decisn":"Batting",
               "addnStatus":"",
               "splStatus":""
            }
         },
         "Tm":[
            {
               "@attributes":{
                  "id":"63",
                  "Name":"Kolkata",
                  "sName":"KOL",
                  "flag":"0"
               }
            },
            {
               "@attributes":{
                  "id":"58",
                  "Name":"Chennai",
                  "sName":"CHN",
                  "flag":"0"
               }
            }
         ],
         "Tme":{
            "@attributes":{
               "Dt":"Apr 20 2013",
               "stTme":"10:30",
               "enddt":"Apr 20 2013"
            }
         },
         "mscr":{
            "inngsdetail":{
               "@attributes":{
                  "noofovers":"50",
                  "rrr":"0",
                  "crr":"6.49",
                  "cprtshp":"11(13)"
               }
            },
            "btTm":{
               "@attributes":{
                  "id":"63",
                  "sName":"KOL"
               },
               "Inngs":{
                  "@attributes":{
                     "desc":"Inns",
                     "r":"66",
                     "Decl":"0",
                     "FollowOn":"0",
                     "ovrs":"10.1",
                     "wkts":"4"
                  }
               }
            },
            "blgTm":{
               "@attributes":{
                  "id":"58",
                  "sName":"CHN"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
EOT;
?>
```

Comment: It says "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/####/public_html/cric/cric.php on line 12"" :(

Please tell me where I am wrong . The line 12 is for each loop .

Comment: Can you please check the same for the full JSON response here https://cdn.anonfiles.com/1366532327809.txt. I am getting the error .

Answer (score 0):

I'm elaborating :

If you wanted to show the whole object as a string with a delimiter, you could do it with a recursive function [for example](http://ideone.com/UUmnOu) :

```
$obj = json_decode($json);

function objectToString($obj, $delimiter = PHP_EOL) {
    foreach($obj as $key=>$val) {

        if(is_object($val) || is_array($val)) {
           objectToString($val, $delimiter);
        } else {
            echo $key . '=> ' .$val . $delimiter;
        }
    }
}

objectToString($obj, '<br />');
```

But it's not really useful or only for debugging, it's easier to just use the [print_r](http://php.net/print_r) function.

Comment: THanks ..I can see the output values as you shown in the example. But how can I make each key as variable?